# Inspect Element/Developer's Tools not producing results sometime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I can run a javascript code, and sometimes it will produce output, sometimes it won't.  If I wait 5-20 mins, I can go back without changing anything and it will work.  Until I nav away and back and then nothing.  This is the same for firefox, IE, and chrome.  I'm doing a fairly simple get.elementsByClassName and then to console log.  Sometimes it produces, and sometimes it doesn't.  I'm trying to scrape data from sonicwall's demo firewall page.  https://realtime.demo.sonicwall.com/main.html

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName ('swlTabContainer 
swlTblContainer');
var csvString = []; 
for(i=0;i<els.length;i++)
{
csvString = els[i].innerText;
console.log(els[i].innerText);
}
var pom = document.createElement('a');
var csvContent=csvString; //here we load our csv data
var blob = new Blob([csvContent],{type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
pom.href = url;
pom.setAttribute('download', 'addgrp.csv');
pom.click();
```

Comment: I understand your description, Can you post your exact code with steps. Sometimes code gives the better idea than description. It can help us to know what you are doing in your code which can help to narrow down the issue. Also inform us, whether this issue occurs with any site or it can only occur with above mentioned site? Which OS (with build version) you are using currently?

Comment: I just edited the post to include the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run that code on that page, that particular is located at NETWORK -> Address objects, -> address groups (click the address groups button at the top). Sometimes you get data, sometimes you don't by running the same code.

Comment: I am wondering, How did you run the above code with IE? In chrome, We can paste the JS code in the console but I does not allow allow the user to paste the JS code in its console.

Comment: I am using both IE and Chrome Dev tools and Inspect Element.    I have no problem inserting it into the browser console.  The thing is, sometimes it returns data, sometimes it don't.  I can run the code and it produce results, then refresh the same page, wait 2 mins and push the up arrow to reload the last code, and I get nothing...

Comment: Here you can see in IE 11 I don't have any option to paste your code in console. https://i.postimg.cc/KYcKpwBp/109.png So it makes me confuse that how you are able to paste the code in IE console and able to run for that site. If i am missing any thing than please try to correct me. I will again try to test the issue and try to provide the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the page you provided, it does seem to load rather slowly.

Perhaps this is an issue of trying to scrape the web data synchronously, when you do it asynchronously with a callback function, once the page has been loaded.

Maybe taking a look at the mdn pages on [load event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
  });
  // scrape for your data
</script>
```

Comment: I'd assumed I could run what you have above and expect the Text, but I still get nothing from the script above.  I would think if the data was on the screen, that it's loaded, but I guess the page is still loading?  If this was the case, how is it I could run a get element and retrieve data, then 10 mins later just hit the up key, and produce the same script and this time nothing?

Comment: What environment are you working in? Are you just typing into the browser's console?

Comment: Yes, Chrome and IE

Comment: I made a test with IE and Chrome several times. I also wait for a page to get load completely. But in both browsers, I am getting an error. In IE : https://i.postimg.cc/hG7MN5MF/112.png In Chrome: https://i.postimg.cc/Gm6xPjRX/113.png can you please check the posted code, whether there is any issue with it or not.